# Why will texmaker not hide R code?

Tags: linux, r, knitr, texmaker

I'm running this code in Texmaker 4.1 on Ubuntu Linux and for some reason the "echo = FALSE" option is not deleting the code from the final pdf.  Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Using R, we can plot the graph of $f(x) = \sin(x)$:

<< echo = FALSE  >>=
x = (1:50)/10
plot(x, sin(x))
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've compiled the document in RStudio (viewer=Okular) and no code is presented...

Comment: Does that mean it should do the same from Texmaker?

Comment: Well, I think that RStudio and Texmaked use the same knitr and TeX compiler, so the output should be the same (are you sure you are able to produce the figure in this example)?